# Cassandra Snapshot

Tags: cassandra, database-backups, snapshot

I have around **5 TB Cassandra cluster** in my organization. We plan to take a full backup (*snapshot on all keyspaces at cluster level*) to another mount point with a retention period of 10 days. Can someone guide me what could be the best size for this mount point.

Comment: Is the 5 TB value including replicas? Is this a single DC?

Answer (score 0):

Snapshots are taken per node. For a cluster-wide snapshot, use a parallel ssh utility (pssh) to execute `nodetool snapshot -t snapshot_name` across a cluster; this will provide an eventually consistent backup of the cluster.

The snapshot will be created in `data_directory_location/keyspace_name/table_name-UUID/snapshots/snapshot_name`.

If your mount point is local, it will need to be large enough to accommodate the total size of the snapshot files at the node-level. If the mount point is remote, it will need to be large enough to contain the combined total of the snapshots for all nodes.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_about_snapshots.html
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsSnapShot.html

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I'm bit interested on numbers. Could someone guide how to estimate the backup size.